# Why can't I underscore (ignore) type variables when creating a type class instance?

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

Here's a simple example:

```
data T a b = T a b deriving (Show)

instance Functor (T a) where
    fmap f (T x y) = T x (f y)
```

Why can't I omit the `a` in the instance declaration, and write something like:

```
instance Functor (T _) where
```

?

The type of `a` is obviously irrelevant for that instance! (And it would be *really* more readable in my opinion).

It's obvious we can ignore *values* of function parameters. Why not allow ignoring values of type variables?

Comment: To clarify - if the answer was "because no one have thought about it", it would at least justify constructing a proposal.

Comment: I could imagine confusion when multiple wildcards were used, e.g. `instance C (T _ _) where ...`.

Comment: @рытфолд What is confusing in your example? The kind of T (`* -> * -> *`) gets reduced to `*` properly, with two first parameters ignored.

Comment: Because it'd be unclear whether they are the same or different type variables.

Comment: @рытфолд Haskell report [explicitly forbids](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-770004.3.2) using the same names for instance declarations, or, IOW, you can't create an instance for a subset of possible type values for a given kind. Which prompts me to write my own answer, I suppose.

Comment: Why would you need this feature?  For values, they have a type and that type has constructors.  We pattern match on the constructors of a particular type.  For types, we have kinds like `*`, `* -> *`, `* -> * -> *`, etc, and we can "pattern match" on constructors of those kinds.  When you write `instance Functor (T a)`, you're "matching" on the kind `* -> *` with the type constructor `T a`, but it wouldn't be useful to write something like `instance Functor _ where` because the constructors for kind `* -> *` are unbounded, while the constructors for a given type are finite....

Comment: ...It might be useful with full dependent types, though, or if we could make our own kinds more easily.  I'm not well versed enough in this area of mathematics to know if this would even be possible.

Comment: It's a feature that would sometimes be useful, but Haskell doesn't have it.  Personally, I use variables like _a, _b etc. for type variables that never matter.

Comment: @bheklilr It would be useful for a reason analogous to why underscores are useful in function definitions: as human-readable, machine-checkable documentation that the type variable plays no important role, and in particular doesn't appear in the instance context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, type class instance parameters don't abide the rules of pattern matching, for which `_` is designed to work as I'd like it to.

Haskell explicitely forbids creating instances where type variables repeat:

> An instance declaration introduces an instance of a class. Let class cx => C u where { cbody } be a class declaration. The general form of the corresponding instance declaration is: `instance cx′ => C (T u1 … uk) where { d }` where k ≥ 0. The type (T u<sub>1</sub> … u<sub>k</sub>) must take the form of a type constructor T applied to simple type variables u<sub>1</sub>, … u<sub>k</sub>; furthermore, T must not be a type synonym, and the ui must all be distinct.
>
> This prohibits instance declarations such as:
>
> ```
>  instance C (a,a) where ...  
>  instance C (Int,a) where ...  
>  instance C [[a]] where ...
> ```

The possibility to "type-pattern-match" in instance declarations is most probably way more complicated and might have different implications, so I can see why `_` wasn't introduced;.

Comment: Surely this restriction makes it _more_ acceptable to allow `_` in instances, since it answers the ambiguity question of "Are the two `_` in `instance C (T _ _)` equal or not?" with a firm "No!", and in fact suggests an implementation strategy of simply inserting fresh type variable names in place of each underscore. I mean it's not as if `f a a = a` is a valid function definition, either.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's an interesting remark! I'll have to dig around that particular area a bit more, but it might just be it could be worth a proposal.